# Why doesn't my leaderstats save when i lift?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

when I lift my weight inside the game and then i leave it doesnt save but when I change my leaderstats with current:server it saves

this is the scripts

data store script:

```
local ds = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("SaveData")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    wait()
    local plrkey = "id_"..plr.UserId
    local save1 = plr.leaderstats.Strength
    local save2 = plr.leaderstats.Rebirths
    
    local GetSaved = ds:GetAsync(plrkey)
    if GetSaved then
        save1.Value = GetSaved[1]
        save2.Value = GetSaved[2]
    else
        local NumberForSaving = {save1.Value, save2.Value}
        ds:GetAsync(plrkey, NumberForSaving)
    end
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(plr)
    ds:SetAsync("id_"..plr.UserId, {plr.leaderstats.Strength.Value, plr.leaderstats.Rebirths.Value})
end)
```

Comment: In your `else` statement, did you intend to use `GetAsync` instead of `SetAsync`?

Comment: @Kylaaa i honestly dont know because ima be honest i took this script from a youtube video because i dont really know how to code datastores yet i was wondering if i just posted it here someone would help me out and help me somehow save the data when my characher lifts a item